# How can i Face Detection during video call in android or flutter?

Tags: twilio, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, videocall

I Have used  the already **Firebase ML kit** but its working fine on an capture images or live device camera BUT how will this work **During the video call**.(we used **Twilio video calling SDK** in my application)
is anyone can give me some **suggestions** ? thank you very much in advance..)):

Comment: Is is on Android or iOS?

Comment: @DongChen Both side we needed

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal You would need to check in the Twilio SDK docs on how to get access to the individual video frames which you can then feed to the ML Kit Face Detection API (examples with various input formats: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android#2.-prepare-the-input-image). We don't have specific experience with the Twilio SDK to give you more guidance.